# Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 The multi-part identifier "a.calendar" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, ssms

```
create table master_mind_table 
(
Item_code           hrcd constraint item_code_const check(item_code='LTC'),
Employee_code       hrempcode,
calendar            hrcd,
elig_carry_eff_from datetime,
elig_carry_eff_to   datetime
primary key (Employee_code,elig_carry_eff_from,elig_carry_eff_to)
)

insert into  master_mind_table 
(item_code,employee_code,elig_carry_eff_from,elig_carry_eff_to
)
select item_code,employee_code,min(year_start_date),min(year_end_date) from hrrtsup_emp_elig_maintain where item_code ='ltc' group by item_code,employee_code order by employee_code

update master_mind_table set a.calendar=b.calendar_code
from master_mind_table a,hrrtsup_emp_elig_maintain b
where a.elig_carry_eff_from=b.year_start_date
and a.elig_carry_eff_to=b.year_end_date
and a.employee_code=b.employee_code
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 The multi-part identifier
>   "a.calendar" could not be bound.

Comment: It's a fishy syntax, you're updating a table, but changing a value in another one. For starter change the update statement to "update a set ..", cause 'a' is the alias for the table you're changing. And make it easier to read, use ANSI syntax for joins please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update a
   set a.calendar=b.calendar_code 
from 
   master_mind_table a,hrrtsup_emp_elig_maintain b 
where 
   a.elig_carry_eff_from=b.year_start_date and 
   a.elig_carry_eff_to=b.year_end_date and a.employee_code=b.employee_code
```